# php emulate class name

Tags: php, oop

I am implementing something like an object factory in PHP.
I have:

```
class Factory{
   public static function createObject($objectType){
      $object = new ObjectParent();
      //... implement specific code for objectChild of the given type 
      return $object;     
   }
}

class ObjectParent(){

}
```

This way, i get an object, it's class name is going to be ObjectParent; I don't have a class for each ObjectChild i want to create, so i would like to be able to do:

```
$newObject = Factory::createObject('myObjectType');
echo get_class($newObject);
//result -> 'myObjectType'
```

is this even possible? how?
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static function createObject($objectType){
  eval('class '.$objectType.' extends ObjectParent {}');
  return new $objectType();   
}
```

Comment: but i don't have a class $objectType

Comment: `$objectType` is a parameter of the factory method. Just try it :)

Comment: ah, I see. In this case you need to use `eval()` - `eval('class '.$objectType.' extends ObjectParent {}')` But I would recommend to recheck the issue, because the `eval()` is evil and I don't think that you really can't specify all the children classes manually

Comment: yes, that is exactly what i want. would you edit your answer so i can accept it please?
Thanx